# Why is my variable undefined inside the Underscore.js each function?

Tags: javascript, variables, underscore.js

Here is my code:

```
TextClass = function () {
    this._textArr = {};
};

TextClass.prototype = {
    SetTexts: function (texts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            this._textArr[texts[i].Key] = texts[i].Value;
        }
    },
    GetText: function (key) {
        var value = this._textArr[key];
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? 'N/A' : value;
    }
};
```

I'm using the Underscore.js library and would like to define my SetTexts function like this:

```
_.each(texts, function (text) {
    this._textArr[text.Key] = text.Value;
});
```

but _textArr is undefined when I get into the loop.

Comment: Because `this` inside the callback is not the same as outside it. Use the third parameter to `each` to pass the context you want to have inside the callback.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In JavaScript, the function context, known as `this`, works [rather differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function).

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Use a temporary variable to store the context:

   ```
   SetTexts: function (texts) {
     var that = this;
     _.each(texts, function (text) {
       that._textArr[text.Key] = text.Value;
     });
   }
   ```
2. Use the third parameter to [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) to pass the context:

   ```
   SetTexts: function (texts) {
     _.each(texts, function (text) {
       this._textArr[text.Key] = text.Value;
     }, this);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass `this` as context for `_.each` call like this:

```
_.each(texts, function (text) {
    this._textArr[text.Key] = text.Value;
}, this);
```

See the docs for http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a million to all repliers :-)

Answer (score 1):

`this` in javascript does not work the same way as you would expect. read this article:
http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

**short version:**

the value of `this` changes every time you call a function. to fix, set another variable equal to `this` and reference that instead

```
TextClass = function () {
    this._textArr = {};
};

TextClass.prototype = {
    SetTexts: function (texts) {
        var that = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            that._textArr[texts[i].Key] = texts[i].Value;
        }
    },
    GetText: function (key) {
        var value = this._textArr[key];
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? 'N/A' : value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also pass things other that "this".  For example, I do something like:

```
var layerGroupMasterData = [[0],[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10]];

_.each(layerGroupMasterData,function(layerGroup,groupNum){
    _.each(layerGroup, function (layer, i) {
            doSomethingThatComparesOneThingWithTheOverallGroup(layerGroupMasterData,layer);
    },layerGroups);
},layerGroupMasterData);
```