# 'this' keyword means differently at two places?

Tags: javascript

Following is my code -

```
(function($){
obj = {
    alertText: function(){
        console.log('Called');
    },
    testFunc: function(){
        console.log(this);
        this.alertText();
    },
    checkFunc: function(){
        inner();
        function inner(){
            console.log(this);
            this.alertText();
        }
    }
}})(jQuery)
```

When I call `testFunc()`, `alertText()` is properly called over the **this** keyword.

However the call to `alertText()` using **this** fails inside `inner()` (TypeError saying this.alertText is not a function) after I call the `checkFunc()` function.

When I console **this** as shown above, I get different contents inside it - the one inside `testFunc()` show the object `obj`, while the one inside `inner()` shows the `Window` object.

Why is this so? Why does **this** mean differently at two places?

Comment: [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Pass your "this" from outer function, to call alertText.

Comment: `this` will mean something different in every function.

Comment: @lonesomeday ok.. but why is that so? can you please explain? sorry i am not quite clear at this concept..

Comment: Possible duplicate: [In Javascript, why is the “this” operator inconsistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/80084/710446)

Comment: not a duplicate of that one, here the `this` making issues is from an inner function in an object.

Comment: I think that that proposed duplicate will certainly clarify the OP's problem, but perhaps you're right that further explanation is required to correct the OP's misunderstanding of how `this` works in inner functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` keyword in javascript is dependent on the calling context, and has a multiple semantic. That's one of the most complicated and bizarre feature of Javascript. You can read @DarkCthulhu's [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

In javascript there are three ways of defining the `this` object, as well explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644086/1290438):

1. someThing.someFunction(arg1, arg2, argN)
2. someFunction.call(someThing, arg1, arg2, argN)
3. someFunction.apply(someThing, [arg1, arg2, argN])

As you call the inner function without an object, `this` points to the global object. Whereas the `this` for `checkFunc` and `testFunc` is the current object that you assign to `obj`.

To solve your issue, in the outer function, create a `var that = this` and use `that` in the inner function. It's adviced by Crockford ;-)

Comment: ok got it.. but can u explain what does 'defining' `this` object mean as you said in your answer? shouldn't `this` implicitly refer to something?

Comment: the `this` object is implicitly defined through the way you call the function, as I told you. Whether you call it unbounded, or bounded to the object.