# Can member-methods of objects be called without bind?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to call inc of obj without bind?

```
 function callIt(callback){
   callback();
 }

 var obj = {
    count: 0,
    inc: function(){
       this.count++;
    }
 };

 callIt(obj.inc.bind(obj));
 obj.count;// 1
```

Question is relevant to me because of older IE-versions that do not support the method bind.

Comment: Have a look at [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) for alternative solutions.

Comment: My recommendation is to use [`es5-shim.js`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) (or equivalent) and move on with more interesting problems. Alternatively, a shim/polyfill can be found in [MDN's Function.bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: That is a related source with interesting answers to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function value

```
callIt(function() { obj.inc(); });
```

Comment: Then why not just use [a shimmed] bind?

Comment: @user2864740 the OP specifically said they couldn't use that because of an IE restriction