# Self invoking function inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, object, scope, closures, object-literal

I'm creating a method inside of an object literal that relies upon passing the 'this' value of the object literal inside of a self invoking function.  A simple example would be:

```
var obj = {
  whoAmI: function(){console.log('I\'m this: ' + this + ' object that exists with it\'s own scope')},

  getThis: (function(self){return self})(this)
}

console.log( obj.whoAmI() ); // shows the value of this as the object literal

console.log( obj.getThis );  // logs the window object to the console
```

I understand that the object literal creates it's own disposable scope, but I'm surprised that I could not pass the value of 'this' from the object literal as a parameter to the anonymous function.

Comment: you call the anon before the obj is done parsing. if you wait to call it, _this_ will be the obj object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function

Comment: During the time the object is created, it doesn't exist yet. You can't pass the `obj` there (and you can't expect that `this` would have the object literal's eventual value).

Comment: @Bergi thanks this is exactly what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations#answer-4616273