# execution context and (( this object ))

Tags: javascript

// I don't understand why this is not working

```
y = 'window';
var x = {
    y : 'x',
    func : function(){
        return function(){
            return this.y
        }
    }
};

x.func()();

// when I execute x.func()() I understand why it should return y
// x.func() would return a function in the global context and then execute it ' should return 'window' '
y = 'window'
var x = {
    y : 'x',
    func : function(){
        return function(){
            return this.y
        }()
    }
};

x.func();
```

why would this code also return 'window' it is executed inside of the x object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript "this" pointer within nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `x.func()()` calls the function `x.func` using `x` as a context, then calls the value it returned using no context. Where the function was defined doesn’t matter; only how it was called does.

To avoid this, you can bind the function to a particular context before returning that:

```
var x = {
    y: 'x',
    func: function() {
        return function() {
            return this.y;
        }.bind(this);
    }
};
```

ES6 arrow functions also use a lexical `this`, equivalent to `bind`:

```
var x = {
    y: 'x',
    func: function() {
        return () => this.y;
    }
};
```

Comment: yes problem is with the second snippet ? 
this => gets evaluated at run time .
it should return 'x' rather than 'window' right ?

Comment: @user3260606: `(function () {})()` doesn’t execute with any context either, regardless of where it’s defined. `x.func()`, `x['func']()`, `func.call(x, …)`, and `func.apply(x, […])` are the only ways a function will be called with a non-default `this`.