# use strict not allow use of this in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

After using 'use strict' statement in my js file it does not allow me to use javascript **this** after ist level

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  a: function() {
    var self = this //works fine upto this level
    var name = 'atul';
    function b() {
      this.name = name; //gives me error as can not set property name of undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is this a bug in javascript compiler??

Comment: man but i want t use this in the second function and i also want to make the scope of the variable inside function b

Comment: please check my answer the last part addresses using this in the function. @AtulAgrawal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "this" pointer within nested function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function)

Comment: but that is working fine for me  Javascript "this" pointer within nested function – Krzysztof Safjanowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** and Javascript:

1. **this** references to the global object by default. ("window" on browsers)
2. **this** references to the calling object example:

   ```
   var x = {name: "x", alphabet: function(){return this;}};
   x.alphabet(); // in this line, x is the calling object
   ```

   this will show you the object itself.
3. So when you do:

   ```
   ...
   a: function() {
     var self = this //works fine upto this level
     var name = 'atul';
     function b() {
       this.name = name; //use strict is trying to tell you something
     }// you won't have a calling object for this function.
   }
   ...
   ```

use-strict says: this function is not even an object property or **method**. Since it's not a method it's **this** will point to the global object and lead to error prone development.

If you wish to use your code in this particular way.

```
module.exports = {
  a: {
       name: 'atul';
       b: function (name) {
         this.name = name; // now you have a as the property which can be called by an object a.
         //To be used as OBJECT.a.b();
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: i can also use by creating a blank object in function a and then call it by using obj.b

Comment: If that's an answer do post it. if that's a question, I need to see the code :) @AtulAgrawal

Comment: var obj ={};
        obj.b= function(){
            this.name = name;  //gives me error as can not read property name of undefined
            console.log(this.name);    
        }
 obj.b();

Comment: this is basically the answer

Comment: You have created a blank object first, then you are trying to set this.name to a name. you neither have name in the function nor this.name is a property. why? obj has no property called name. @AtulAgrawal

Comment: can we continue this on chat??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110225/discussion-between-atul-agrawal-and-amresh-venugopal).

Answer (score -1):

`this` is undefined as it is not autoboxed to an object in strict mode.

> First, the value passed as this to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed"). For a normal function, this is always an object: either the provided object if called with an object-valued this; the value, boxed, if called with a Boolean, string, or number this; or the global object if called with an undefined or null this. (Use call, apply, or bind to specify a particular this.) Not only is automatic boxing a performance cost, but exposing the global object in browsers is a security hazard, because the global object provides access to functionality that "secure" JavaScript environments must restrict. Thus for a strict mode function, the specified this is not boxed into an object, and if unspecified, this will be undefined

Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript)

Comment: That means `'use strict' function test(){ console.log(this); } test(); // returns undefined new test(); // returns object`