# Javascript this keyword inside functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, internals, ecma

I am trying to understand internals of `Javascript`. I have some misunderstanding of `this` keyword. 
Everywhere stated that `this` keyword is reference to the object that invokes function.

But as far as I know `function` is an object as well.
So consider this example

```
var car = {
  brand: "Nissan",
  getBrand: function(){
    var closure = function(){
      console.log(this.brand);
      console.log(this);
    };
    return closure();
  }
};

car.getBrand();
```

Why does `this` reference inside `closure` point to the `global` object instead of `getBrand` wrapping function ? Again everything is object in javascript, so I cannot understand this behavior.

Please explain this from internals perspective.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a closer duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9644044/1666547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is determined by how `function` is called..`closure` is called with no reference of `context` and global context is `window`(*in Browser*)

Use [**`Function.prototype.call`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to specify `this` context while function is `invoked`

```js
var car = {
  brand: "Nissan",
  getBrand: function() {
    var closure = function() {
      console.log(this.brand);
      console.log(this);
    };
    return closure.call(this);
  }
};

car.getBrand();
```