# Ionic 2 Angular 2 - can't access NavController from method

Tags: javascript, ionic2, ionic3, lexical-scope

I am trying to navigate to another page after user is authenticated with angularfire. Everything works except navigating to another page.

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menu: MenuController, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFireDatabase, private platform  : Platform) {
    this.navigateIfUserIsLogdIn();
  }

  navigateIfUserIsLogdIn(){
        this.authState = this.afAuth.authState;
        this.user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

        this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
          }
        });
  }
```

The error I get is:

***Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'navCtrl' of undefined***

Why wont it work when inside navigateIfUserIsLogdIn() ?

please help, and provide an example :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "this" pointer within nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions like this:

```
navigateIfUserIsLogdIn(){
    this.authState = this.afAuth.authState;
    this.user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
}
```

Notice that now we do

`this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {...});`

instead of

`this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {`

By using arrow functions, **the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance** (otherwise, the `this` keyword points to the inner function, and `navCtrl` is not defined in it).

Comment: Greate answer! Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score -2):

try to do that

```
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public menu: MenuController, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFireDatabase, private platform  : Platform) {
    this.navigateIfUserIsLogdIn();
  }

  navigateIfUserIsLogdIn(){
        this.authState = this.afAuth.authState;
        this.user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
        var that= this;
        this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            that.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: At least explain why, and point out the option of using `=>`. Really, though, this is a duplicate