# How to call a function inside bluebirdjs promise

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am trying to get a promise function with bluebirdjs. but all attempts falling my way because maybe I don't know what I am doing...?

I want to get files locations, then download the files one after the other then push to an array.

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
fileFunction(files){
  Promise.map(files, function(file) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    //Promise.delay(1000);
     return this.getLocation(file); 
    },
  ).then((file) => {
      console.log('done')
    });

}

getLocation(file){
 if(file){
  return this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => 
      this.img_array.push(url)
  );
 }
```

When I call the return this.getLocation(file)... I get the following `error
bluebird.js:1545 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of undefined    ....bluebird.js`

**Edit part of the code am using now!**

```
 fileFunction(files){
    return Promise.map(files, file => {
       return this.getDownloadUrl(file); 
    }).then(locations => {
        // add these locations onto this.img_array
        this.img_array.push(...locations);
        console.log('done');
        return locations;
    });
  }


getFiles(e): Promise<any>{
  this.outPutFiles = e;

 this.fileFunction(this.outPutFiles).then(locations => {
  locations.map((arr) => arr.subscribe((files) => this.downloadUrls.push(files)));
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
}


getDownloadUrl(file){
  if(file){
    return this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL();
   } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('No file passed to getLocation'));
   }
}
```

Comment: Try an arrow function for the Promise: `Promise.map(files, (file) => {`…`})`. See [Javascript “this” pointer within nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36526580/4642212).

Comment: Why are you calling the `getLocation` function as member of `this` value?

Comment: @undefined, my aim is to get the file, where should I call the getLocation?

Comment: The function is hosted in that context. You can simply code: `return getLocation(file);`

Comment: @undefined You can assume that `getLocation` and `fileFunction` are both methods of some outer object or class, so `this.getLocation` is correct. `getLocation(){}` by itself wouldn’t be valid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it is! thanks. @undefined I wanted the getLocation to run one after another! In async sequence

Comment: @Xufox Of course. Missing `function` keyword. Since there are many transpilers that does magic stuff, I have assumed the code somehow syntactically is valid, otherwise before the `TypeError`, a `SyntaxError` should be thrown. Maybe that's not the complete related code!

Comment: @Xufox thanks. How do I make sure the getLocation function completes in a async fashion? Such that, file at index 0 is downloaded and pushed before file at index 1....and so on?

Comment: @Xufox - Except that `this.getLocation(file)`  isn't valid because `this` is not what the OP wants it to be - it's not the parent object because it's inside another callback function.  Using an arrow function for `Promise.map()` would fix that part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`this.getLocation(file)` does not work because you've lost the value of `this` because you're inside a `Promise.map()` callback.  Remember, that every normal function call in Javascript changes the value of `this` unless you specifically control the value of `this`.

You can fix that part of the issue with a simple arrow function for your callback like this:

```
fileFunction(files){
  return Promise.map(files, file => {
     return this.getLocation(file); 
  }).then(locations => {
      // add these locations onto this.img_array
      this.img_array.push(...locations);
      console.log('done');
      return locations;
  });
}
```

This assumes that `this.getLocation(file)` returns a promise that resolves to the location value.  Are you sure it does that?  It looks like there may be more to your problem than just that first error you ran into.

---

And, after a side conversation, you also need to fix `getLocation()` to return a promise that resolves to the desired URL.  Looking in the firebase Javascript doc, it appears that `getDownloadURL()` already returns a promise that resolves to the desired URL.  So, you can just return that promise and let `Promise.map()` manage the results for you.

```
getLocation(file){
 if(file){
  return this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL();
 } else {
  return Promise.reject(new Error("No file passed to getLocation"));
 }
}
```

---

And, then you would use it all like this:

```
obj.fileFunction(fileArray).then(locations => {
    console.log(locations);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This works, except that, I think the `this.getLocation(file)` isn't called in an async manner. The `this.img_array` array files index are not the same as in the `files` array. ```this.files=[0: "xngb", 1: "bdje"]``` but in the downloaded urls I get  ```this.img_array=[0: "...bdje", 1: "...xngb"]```. How do I make sure the getLocation(file) functions works async? thanks

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - What do you mean "how do I make sure the `getLocation(file)` is called async"?  The implementation of `getLocation()` either is async or it's not.  It isn't the caller that determines that.  It's the implementation of `getLocation()` that determines that and what it calls and what it returns (it should be returning a promise that resolves with the desired value if it's async).

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - `Promise.map()` will maintain order of the items for you.  Trying to push items into the array yourself with `this.img_array.push(url)` is a mistake.  You should get the resolved values from `Promise.map()` and then they will be in the right order.

Comment: ```getLocation(file){ return  this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => 
     // console.log(url)
     this.img_array.push(url)
  );}``` is my get location function. As I was trying to get the resulting ```this.img_array``` files index to match the index of the files in the ```files``` array. thanks

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - Does `getLocation()` return a promise?  I have no idea what `this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(...)` is so I can't look it up in any doc to learn more about it.

Comment: it returns a firebase subscription...```return this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => // console.log(url) this.img_array.push(url) );```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178661/discussion-between-obasi-obeny-oj-and-jfriend00).

Comment: If a firebase subscription isn't a promise, it won't work with `Promise.map()`.  I don't know firebase so I can't really help you with that part.

Comment: ``console.log(locations)`` returns observables, and what is the obj. property from?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - `obj` in `obj.fileFunction()` is whatever your object is that has the method `.fileFunction()`.

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - According to this [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL). `_storage.ref().getDownloadURL()` returns a promise that resolves to the url.  `Promise.map()` will wait for those promises to resolve and it's `.then()` handler will be passed an array of urls in proper order.  For me to help you debug your fixed up code, you would have to show me exactly what code you're running by adding it to the end of your current question and formatting it properly.  I can't debug code I can't see.  I won't be awake much longer.

Comment: Thanks! I added the code am using. the major change is the ``` locations.map((arr) => arr.subscribe((files) => this.downloadUrls.push(files)));``` so as to have an array of the files.

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj - I've taken this as far as I can tonight.  I have no idea what you're trying to do with `arr.subscribe()`.  `locations` should be an array of download URLs which I thought was the whole point here.

Comment: Thnks, u did alot! I thought so. but it returns an array of observables. That's why I use the arr.subscribe. ```4) [Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable]
0:Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
1:Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
2:Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
3:Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}```