# JavaScript Objects not instantiating

Tags: javascript, oop, p5.js

I have a class `dynObj`, but it appears that seperate instances of it adopt the values of the most recently defined instance.

```js
draw() {
    tmov1 = new dynObj(args...); //Displays as a white ball on webpage, as intended
    tmov2 = new dynObj(different args...); //Seemingly overwrites the properties of tmov1
    objects.push(tmov1, tmov2)
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].dostuff() //Normally causes the object to display as intended,
        };                   //but will only ever display one
};
```

The class dynObj is as follows:

```js
class baseObj {
  constructor(position, dimentions, properties) {
    this.pos = createVector(position.x,position.y) || null;
    this.shape = properties.shape
    if (this.shape == "ellipse") {
      this.dim = dimentions || {diam:0}
    } else if (this.shape == "quadrilateral") {
      this.dim = dimentions || { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
  };
};

class dynObj extends baseObj {
  constructor(position, dimentions, suvat, properties) {
    super(position, dimentions, properties);
    self = this
    self.type = 'dynamic'
    self.properties = properties 
    //more definitions with self.x = someval
  };
  getDistance(a,b){
    if (a == undefined || b == undefined) return false;
    var dist = p5.Vector.sub(b,a)
    //console.log(dist)
    return dist
  };
  tick(ticksize) {
    self.assignLastTick(function(lasttick){
      self.lasttick = lasttick
      self.time = self.time + ticksize
      self.updateSuvat(ticksize)
    })    
  };
  //assorted methods...
}
```

Why do the instances affect eachother?
(Can supply a link to this in action if more context is needed)

Comment: Where is the `someClass` class?

Comment: I suspect you're passing the same `properties` object when creating both objects. The class doesn't make a copy of the properties, it just stores a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a global variable `self`, and using that instead of `this`. All the instances are accessing the same global variable, which contains the value of `this` from the last object that was created.

In the callback function in `tick()`, you need a way to reference the original object, so you need to bind a local variable `self` there, rather than using a global variable. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

```
class dynObj extends baseObj {
  constructor(position, dimentions, suvat, properties) {
    super(position, dimentions, properties);
    this.type = 'dynamic'
    this.properties = properties 
    //more definitions with this.x = someval
  };
  getDistance(a,b){
    if (a == undefined || b == undefined) return false;
    var dist = p5.Vector.sub(b,a)
    //console.log(dist)
    return dist
  };
  tick(ticksize) {
    let self = this;
    this.assignLastTick(function(lasttick){
      self.lasttick = lasttick
      self.time = self.time + ticksize
      self.updateSuvat(ticksize)
    })    
  };
  //assorted methods...
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `this` in Javascript inside nested functions. The `tick` method's `this` won't generally be the same as the callback function's `this` - hence the need to sometimes declare a variable like `var self = this;` so that `self` can be referred to from within the callback function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks, didn't notice the nested function.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. The `this.time` in the above should be `self.time`, however.