# I am confused with the 'this' keyword in arrow function for this case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, arrow-functions

I have two cases and I am confused with the output I am getting.

**Case 1 :**

```js
let x = {
  b: 5,
  y: function a() {
    return function() {
      return () => {
        console.log(this);
      }
    }
  }
}
x.y()()();
```

On running `x.y()()()` I am getting `Window` object as output but according to arrow function's definition, the output should have been its parent function.

**Case 2 :**

```js
let x = {
  b: 5,
  y: function a() {
    return () => {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
}
x.y()();
```

If I remove one level of nesting which is a basic example then on running `x.y()()`, I am getting object `x` as output.

Can you please explain why exactly am I getting these output?

Comment: Arrow functions have no this. Inside an arrow function the this keyword is the this of the upper scope.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Probably because a() in Case 1 is not an arrow function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` inside a function is determined by its calling context, and by whether the function is an arrow function or not.

With an arrow function, `this` is always inherited from the outer scope.

If the function being called is a full `function` *and* that function is being called as a property as an object (eg `obj.foo()`), then the calling context, the `this` inside the `foo` function, is `obj`.

If the function being called is a full `function` but is *standalone* - that is, not a property of an object - then there is no calling context, and `this` inside the function will be `undefined` or the global object.

With

```js
let x = {
  b: 5,
  y: function a() {
    return function() {
      return () => {
        console.log(this === window);
      }
    }
  }
}
x.y()()();
```

The `this` is what the returned function's `this` is - that is, the calling context for the function invoked here:

```
x.y()()
```

The function being invoked is not part of an object - it's a standalone function expression which was created from the invocation of a *prior* function on an object, equivalent to:

```
(x.y())()
```

So, there is no calling context, and `this` is the global object.

In contrast, in case 2, the closest ancestor `function` being called is the `a` function on the `y` property of the object, and this function *is* called with a calling context:

```
x.y()()
^^^^^
```

Above, `y` is called with a calling context of `x`, so `this` is `x` inside the `a` function.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.
I have one more doubt, can you please clarify for this case also -
I am getting Window object in this case.
let x = {
    b: 5,
    y: () => {
        console.log(this);
        return function () {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
}

x.y()()

Comment: The first `this` is in an arrow function, inherited from the top level. The second `this` is in the returned function which, when called, is not called on an object.

Comment: For first 'this' why is it not considering context of object 'x' as it is an arrow function and x is its parent?

Comment: Inside an arrow function, `this` refers to the `this` of the outer scope. The outer scope there is the top level, and `this` on the top level is the global object or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The first function call is

```
x.y()
```

In that function call, `this` will refer to `x`. That function call returns a function, which is used in the second function call:

```
x.y()()
```

*That* function call has no explicit `this` value, so `this` is `window`.  That function call returns *another* function, the innermost arrow function, which upon its definition inherits `window` as `this` from its closure. Thus the third function call:

```
x.y()()()
```

also has `window` as the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to this question:-[Javascript "this" pointer within nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644044/javascript-this-pointer-within-nested-function)

Calling a function inside a parent object that is 
 - in case of x.y(), it has a leading parent x, that's why it returned x 
 - in case of x.y()() & x.y()()(), there the insider function is called which don't have a leading parent object and hence that will return window.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's What's Going On...

First, let's modify your code slightly -- but before we even do that, let's talk about *what even influences `this`*: "CallSite".

### CallSite

Where you call a function from will determine its `this` value and there is an *order of precedent* which goes alongside such determination. Basically, there are 4 types of CallSite, *however*, there 1 or 2 caveats which arguably makes this 5 or 6 types.

#### The 4 Types of CallSite

- Global
- Implicit
- Explicit
- New

Global

This is fairly obvious & straightforward... Call a function detached from any object and `this` will be the *Global Scope*:

```js
function run() {
  this === window === true;
}
```

Implicit

Also fairly straightforward. Call any function as a method of an object and `this` will equal that object's instance.

```js
function run() { return this; }
run();  // Global
({ id: 'test', run: run }).run();  // > { id: 'test', run: f() }
```

Explicit (See Caveat Below)

Straightforward. Calling a function using `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply` will *force* `this` to equal the first argument of the prototype method. However, there is one caveat to this rule -- stay tuned.

```js
(function run() { return this; }).call(new Klass());  // this instanceof Klass === true
```

New

As straightforward as it gets. Call a function and prefix the invocation with `new` and `this` will equal a new instance of the implied class. However, this does have one exception.

#### Caveats to CallSite Precedence

Explicit

`Function.prototype.call` & `Function.prototype.apply` **cannot force a function's context if the function is the result of calling `Function.prototype.bind`**. Moreover, it is noteworthy to mention that *recalling `Function.prototype.bind` on an already bound function will not re-bind to another context; its `this` value will remain the same as that of the original `bind` call*.

```js
function run() { return this; }
let o = { };
let x = { };
let r = run.bind(o);
let result = r.call(x);  // result === x === false && result === o === true
```

New

**When calling a function that is prefixed with `new`, you will not get an object-instance of the implied class if the function returns a different value**.

```js
class Class {}
var Klass = function Klass() {
    return new Class;
};
var klass = new Klass();  // klass instanceof Class === true
```

## Your Code (Modified)

In your original code, you get back the value of `x` because *Arrow-Functions always bleed the outermost scope into their own*. That is, an arrow-function will always take its *parent-scope's `this` context*. This behavior **is no different returning the result of calling `Function.prototype.bind` on a function and providing `this` as its context**.

```js
var x = {
  b: 5,
  y: function a() {
    console.log('a', this);
    return function b() {
      console.log('b', this);  // window
    }
    return () => {
      console.log('=>', this);  // x
    }
  }
}
x.y()();
```

When we call `x.y()` we are returning whatever that function returns. I have modified your code to present two return scenarios:

- Returning `function b() {...}`: `x.y()` is a detached function. Therefore, its CallSite will be *Global*
- Returning `() => {...}`: `x.y()` is a detached Arrow-Function. Its behavior will be as if you invoked `bind` on a normative function and passed in the [parent] function's `this` context as the first argument.

## Closing

I hope this makes a lot more sense after further understanding CallSite. Knowing this, you realize it is possible to actually use `new` as an invocation tactic. That is, try to figure out how the following code could run successfully:

### Exercise 1 (The "Crockford Dog Balls Problem")

What behavior do the following 2 lines of code exhibit?

```js
var a = new (function Klass() {})();  // a
var b = new (function Klass() {}());  // b
```

### Exercise 2 ("What's New?")

Write a function that remediates the following code to run successfully.

```js
var instance = new new new new Klass();
```

### Hope this helps!